# Как понять что число начинается и заканчивается одной и той же цифрой?

Tags: c

Натолкните пожалуйста на мысль. Я немного запутался с задачей:
Дано  натуральное  число.   Верно  ли,  что  оно  начинается  и заканчивается одной и той же цифрой?
Сначала пробовал читать в массив, потом считать элементы в массиве, чтобы найти первое и последнее число и потом сравнить. Но не смог до конца допилить с массивом и мне кажется это усложнение с массивом.

Какая логика должна быть в решении?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

зачем вам массивы? в школах вполне себе арифметику пока еще преподают.

последняя цифра - остаток от деления на 10. первая - деление числа на 10 до упора и взятие последнего остатка

```
int mynumber=123456;
int last=mynumber%10;
int first=mynumber;
for(first=mynumber;first>=10;first=first/10);        
first = first%10;
printf("%d  - %d",first,last);
```